# What is a good replacement for paramiko in python 3 ? Or is there a port of paramiko for python 3?

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.x, paramiko

I have python 2.7 code based on the paramiko module that I would like to port to python 3.3 but I cannot seem to find a version of paramiko that would work or a proper replacement.

I need the module to work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Anyone got pointers on this ?

Comment: ["Python 3 support" issue is closed](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16). `paramiko 1.13+` supports Python 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a full port done that passes all tests on Py2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3. Needs testing. You can find it in [pull request #236](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/236) on the main github repo.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a proper replacement but I would be happy to learn that I am wrong. You can use `subprocess` but that kind of defeats the purpose of having a nice module.

The most recent official word from paramiko is [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16):

> No py3k news yet, it is still definitely planned (see my above comment), but other priorities have to come first :(

So no timeline but hope.

Edit: There has been some progress but it doesn't seem to be ready for general use yet. You can follow [this discussion](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16#issuecomment-20860590) for updates.

Edit: Not official but here is a [paramiko fork](https://github.com/nischu7/paramiko) that seems to be working in Python 3.

Comment: Thank You! I guess I will have to monitor the paramiko site for any news and be patient about porting my code.

Comment: I have updated my reply with the link to a working fork (I haven't fully tested but that is the claim of the author)

Answer (score 1):

While you wait for paramiko on Python 3,  you can use putty.

```
os.system('C:\putty\psftp ' + USER_NAME +'@' + SERVER+ ' -pw ' +PASS+' -b '+ SFTPscript)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solutions how install and use paramiko on python 3.3.2 on Windows XP in Internet and it was work :)

```
Need to install
python-3.3.2.msi
paramiko-1.14.0.zip
pycrypto-2.6.win32-py3.3.exe
pypa-setuptools-3.6.tar.gz
ecdsa-0.11.tar.gz
pip-0.7.3.zip
```